# Get list from two models (With addtional fields). Make Subquery

Tags: python, django

I have models Reserved and Room (default status is Free). And i want get list of all Rooms.

Their statuses is

1. Reserved (I have such table)
2. Free (not price, state)
3. Busy

So in short i need to get all Rooms with their status. I don't need status fields and will not add it. No status field in my models. How can i get certain statuses?

Shortly model

```
class Room(models.Model):
    # Default all rooms are Free (Rooms state)
    number = models.ForeignKey(RoomNumber)
    expiry_date = models.DateTimeField()

class Reserved(models.Model):
    visitor = models.ForeignKey(Visitor, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    room = models.OneToOneField(Room)
    reserved_date = models.DateTimeField()
    begin_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

I tried to do Subquery but no result :(

```
    reserved = Reserved.objects\
    .filter(room=OuterRef('pk'))\
    .filter(begin_date=timezone.now())\
    .values(count=Count('pk'))

    Room.objects.annotate(reserved=Subquery(reserved[:1]))
```

If **1** room is Reserved if **0** empty

Comment: Does a reservation not have an end date?

Comment: no it has :) begin_date i just named wrong. Begin date is 'end_date'. Just named wrong

Answer (score 1):

From the top of my head so the syntax might not be accurate.

```
Room.objects.filter(Q(reserved__isnull=False), Q(expiry_date__gt=datetime.date.today()) | Q(reserved_begin_date__lt=datetime.date.today()))
```

But I find your model complicated, also problematic. What would you do if a room is currently reserved, but a second visitor wants to reserve the room for next month? With a 1-1-relationship, this is not possible.

Why not this?

```
class Room(models.Model):
    number = models.ForeignKey(RoomNumber)

class Reservation(models.Model):
    visitor = models.ForeignKey(Visitor, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=...)
    reserved_date = models.DateTimeField()
    begin_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

With that you could just

```
given_date = datetime.date.today()
free_rooms_on_given_date = Room.objects.exclude(begin_date__lt=given_date).exclude(end_date__gt=given_date)
```

Comment: but how i can get status in my template. Busy, reserved, or free?

Comment: I literally told you in the last two line. You just have to change the query parameters. You need to figure out the cases. All three are dependent on a date. Free and Busy are dependet on a given date. And reserved is every room that has a Reservation where begin_date is in the future from now.

Comment: i can't understand your answer really sorry) Your query working fine but in template what to show? {{ ? }}

Comment: Show your template

Comment: Btw, do you understand the design flaw in your model? I suggest that you fix that first and then rephrase your question.